# Use of array list and String comparison

Tags: java

I need to read the names from a array list and compare them using loops and print the values from the array in the list

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UniqueName {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        int wordcount = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("Names.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();

           String str [] = line.split((" "));
              for ( int i = 0; i <str.length ; i ++) {
                if (str [i].length() > 0) {
                  wordcount ++; 

                }

                }

        }
        System.out.println(wordcount);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice requirement. Whay have you tried and where are you stuck? If you did something please post your code here with the specific part you have a problem with.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code. This is not suitable for a comment :)

Comment: Would be nice if you had a string comparison in there somewhere...

Comment: am unaware of string comparison,can anyone help me with this plz

Comment: `if (string1.equals(string2)) { ... }` If the requirement to is to find unique names, then you need to check if the string you are currently looking at has already been seen. This means you will need to keep track of the names as you go.

Comment: ok is it using arrays?

Comment: Since you don't know how many names you will end up having you should use something like `ArrayList`. With an array you either need to know how many items you will have in advance, manually create an array 1 item longer and copy all elements each time you want to add something, or create an array with tons of extra length which is wasteful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UniqueName {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("Names.txt"));
        Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<String>();

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();

           String str [] = line.split((" "));
              for ( int i = 0; i <str.length ; i ++) {
                if (str [i].length() > 0) {
                  wordcount ++; 

                }
                uniqueNames.add(str[i]);

              }

        }

        System.out.println(wordcount);
        System.out.println(uniqueNames);
    }
}
```

Using a set, it only adds the value you pass if it doesn't already exist in it.
Then you can print it out with println(uniqueNames); which will print out each element like so: "[name1, name2, name3, ..., nameN]"

To get rid of the brackets and commas, you can use this:

```
String str = uniqueNames.toString();
str = str.replace('[', '');
str = str.replace(']', '');
str = str.replace(',', '');
```

If you want to get each one on a new line, you can change replace(',', '') to: replace(',', '\n');

Comment: @Mathew -It results in repeated words not unique ones

Answer (score -1):

here you go, try to learn something from it :)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("names.txt"));
    // this is the arraylist to keep all the names from your file
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        // since some of the names have spaces at the end, we pass them
        // trough a cleanup method to remove the spaces
        String line = clearSpaces(input.nextLine());
        // add the cleaned up names to the arraylist
        names.add(line);
    }

    // loop through all the names in the array for comparisson
    for (int c = 0; c < names.size(); c++) {
        // set each name to be unique until proven otherwise
        boolean unique = true;
        // take the name out of the array to test
        String testString = names.get(c);
        // loop through all the other names in the array for comparisson
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            // only if the indexes are different the comparisson makes sense
            if (i != c) {
                // take the name out of the array to test against
                String tempString = names.get(i);
                // test the names against each other
                if (testString.equals(tempString)) {
                    // if they are the same then it's not unique
                    unique = false;
                    // break the loop cause we already know it's not unique
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // only if the unique boolean value is still true
        // after testing against all other names
        if (unique)
            // print the name of that unique name
            System.out.println(testString);
    }
}

// returns a string clean of spaces
private static String clearSpaces(String withSpaces) {
    // string builder for the string output
    StringBuilder withoutSpaces = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = withSpaces.toCharArray();
    // loop the array of characters
    for (char c : chars) {
        // if it's not equal to 32 which corresponds to space char
        if (c != 32) {
            // append it to the string builder
            withoutSpaces.append(c);
        }
    }
    // return all the chars as string
    return withoutSpaces.toString();
}
```

Comment: At least add _some_ sort of explanation.